# Use generics to declare type of return value of class method

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have the following:

```
export class RootCtrl {

  m: Model<any>;

  constructor(m: Model<any>) {
    this.m = m;
  }

  doFindMany(query: object, options?: CDTModelOpts, cb?: MongoErrorCB){

    const Model = this.m;

    // cb is optional, if cb == null, returns promise
    const {populate, lean} = options || ({} as CDTModelOpts);

    let q = Model.find(query);

    if (populate && populate.length > 0) {
      q = q.populate(populate);
    }

    if (lean !== false) {
      q = q.lean();
    }

    return q.lean().exec(cb)
  }

}
```

what I want to do, is declare a return type for this wrapper method...something like this:

```
  doFindMany(query: object, options?: CDTModelOpts, cb?: MongoErrorCB) : Array<typeof this.m> {

    const Model = this.m;

    // cb is optional, if cb == null, returns promise
    const {populate, lean} = options || ({} as CDTModelOpts);

    let q = Model.find(query);

    if (populate && populate.length > 0) {
      q = q.populate(populate);
    }

    if (lean !== false) {
      q = q.lean();
    }

    return q.lean().exec(cb)
  }
```

the return type, is the type of the Model value that gets passed in.
The syntax I use is totally bogus however. Is there a way for the return type to reflect the typeof an input parameter to the constructor?

Comment: Make `RootCtrl` generic? It can be `RootCtrl<T>`, `m` can be `T`, the `constructor` can accept an argument of `T` and `doFindMany` can return `T`.

Comment: jonrsharpe thanks, is that answer from @Vayrex the same as your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need something like here.

```
  export class RootCtrl<ModelType> {

  m: Model<ModelType>;

  constructor(m: Model<ModelType>) {
    this.m = m;
  }

  doFindMany(query: object, options?: CDTModelOpts, cb?: MongoErrorCB): Array<Model<ModelType>>{

    const Model = this.m;

    // cb is optional, if cb == null, returns promise
    const {populate, lean} = options || ({} as CDTModelOpts);

    let q = Model.find(query);

    if (populate && populate.length > 0) {
      q = q.populate(populate);
    }

    if (lean !== false) {
      q = q.lean();
    }

    return q.lean().exec(cb)
  }

}
```